# dask.array.reshape very slow

Tags: arrays, dask

I have an array that I iteratively build up like follows:

```
step1.shape = (200,200)
step2.shape = (200,200,200)
step3.shape = (200,200,200,200)
```

and then reshape to:

```
step4.shape = (200,200**3)
```

I do this because dask.array.atop doesn't seem to allow you to go from a shape like this: (200,200) -> (200,200**2). I think this is so that it is related to chunking and lazy evaluation.

When I do step4 and try to reshape it, dask seems to want to compute the matrix prior to reshaping it which results in significant computation time and memory use.

Is there a way to avoid this?

As requested, here is some dummy code:

```
def prod_mat(matrix_a,matrix_b):
    #mat_a.shape = (300,...,300,200)
    #mat_b.shape = (300, 200)
    mat_a = matrix_a.reshape(-1,matrix_a.shape[-1])
    #mat_a = (300**n,200)
    mat_b = matrix_b.reshape(-1,matrix_b.shape[-1])
    #mat_b = (300,200)
    mat_temp = np.repeat(mat_a,matrix_b.shape[0],axis=0)*np.tile(mat_b.T,mat_a.shape[0]).T
    new_dim = int(math.log(mat_temp.shape[0])/math.log(matrix_a.shape[0]))
    new_shape = [matrix_a.shape[0] for n in range(new_dim)]
    new_shape.append(-1)
    result = mat_temp.reshape(tuple(new_shape))
    #result.shape = (300,...,300,300,200)
    return result

b = np.random.rand(300,200)
b = da.from_array(b,chunks=100)
c=da.atop(prod_mat,'ijk',b,'ik',b,'jk')
d=da.atop(prod_mat,'ijkl',c,'ijl',b,'kl')
e=da.atop(prod_mat,'ijklm',d,'ijkm',b,'lm')
f = e.sum(axis=-1)
f.reshape(300,300**3) ----> This is slow, as if it is using compute()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow the steps of your question.  Can you provide an example operation that you're trying to do that fails or is slow?  Perhaps with random data?

Comment: I'll add it to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This computation isn't calling `compute`, instead it's stuck making a very very large graph.  Generally speaking reshaping parallel arrays is pretty intense.  Lots of your little chunks end up talking to lots of your other little chunks, creating havoc.  This example is particularly bad.

Perhaps there is another way to produce your output in the correct shape initially?

Looking through the development logs it appears that this failure was actually anticipated during development: https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/758

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to be a little bit creative and see how I can avoid it.

Comment: I obviously need some inspiration. Do you have any pointers? Even this toy problem difficult: `e = da.atop(lambda x,y,z:np.einsum('i,j,k->ijk',x,y,z),'ijk',z,'i',z,'j',z,'k')` where all I want to do is flatten the array seems to spend more time flattening than calculating the values...

Comment: I've tried manually reshaping it by using concatenate, but not much luck.